# Converting d hr m s to [h]:mm

Tags: microsoft-excel, format

I have data that is in the format of 'd hr m s' and want to change it to [h]:mm. Where the h is the d*24+hr.

For example, this is the data that I currently have:

[image]

What can I do to format the cell, or what formula can I use to change the cell data to the format that I want?

Cheers

Comment: @Akina i have no experience using VBA at the moment, some other users posted formula's that work well, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creates a time format that Excel will recognize and adds the days

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(A1,FIND("d",A1)-1),0)+(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("hr",A1)),"","00:")&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,IFERROR(FIND("d",A1),-1)+2,LEN(A1)),"hr ",":"),"m ",":"),"s",""))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, this was the solution i needed, cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can effectively solve this using free Excel [RegEx Find/Replace](http://www.codedawn.com/excel-add-ins.php) add-in.

*(I'm not affiliated with the tool.)*

Just enter below  formula, and format results as `[h]:mm`

`=SUMPRODUCT(RegExFind(A2,"(\d+)"),{86400,3600,60,1})/86400`

[image]

Comment: As I understand the way it works, it will return the wrong value if there is no `d` in the string.  Above the OP shows an example of `9hr 37m 41s` which will error as the regEx will only return 3 items to the array.

Comment: Yes, that's right, all parts need to exist.

Answer (score -1):

*Combination of few basic Excel function wrapped with `ISNUMBER` converts the data into desire format.*

[image]

- Formula in Cell `I31`, fill it down.
            `=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("d",H31)),LEFT(H31,FIND("d",H31)-1)*24)+IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("h",H31)),MID(0&H31,MAX(1,FIND("h",0&H31)-2),2))+MID(0&H31,MAX(1,FIND("m",0&H31)-2),2)/60`
- Apply `Appropriate Cell format with 2 Decimals` on `I31:I35`.

---

**Edited:**

*Since by mistake I've skipped OP's need `Results in [H]:mm Time format`, therefore I'm posting this new formula, returns Time is desire format.*

**Readers, just ignore the above shown formula.**

[image]

- Formula in Cell `I46`, fill it down.

  `=SUM(MID(0&H46&"000",FIND({"d","h","m"},0&H46&"xxdhm")-2,2)*{1440,60,1})/86400*60`

**N.B.** Apply `[h]:mm` Time format on `I46:I53`

- Formula in Cell `J46`, fill it down.

  `=TEXT(SUM(MID(0&H46&"000",FIND({"d","h","m"},0&H46&"xxdhm")-2,2)*{1440,60,1})/86400*60,"[h]:mm")`

*Adjust cell reference in the formula as needed.*

Comment: The OP was looking for a `[h]:mm` time format but you're delivering the minutes as decimal of an hour.\; e.g. *85.67*cannot have *67* minutes in an hour.

Comment: @Jeeped,, my mistake  I've missed it !!

Comment: @Jeeped,,, now check the modified version of my post ☺

Comment: That looks better. I wasn't the original down-voter but I've added an upvote to even things out.

Comment: @Jeeped,, not an issue,, thanks for valuable observation.