# How to convert text format 252 hrs 45 m to 252.75 in number format

Tags: microsoft-excel

How to convert text format 252 hrs 45 m to 252.75 in number format in Excel.
Employee working hours coming as 252 hrs 45 minutes . How to convert this text format to number format so we can calculate all paydata in excel
Thanks

Comment: see: https://superuser.com/questions/1493125/converting-d-hr-m-s-to-hmm/1493442#1493442

Comment: and: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59686582/excel-functions-to-covert-x-days-x-hours-x-minutes-in-actual-minutes/59686718#59686718

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting d hr m s to \[h\]:mm](https://superuser.com/questions/1493125/converting-d-hr-m-s-to-hmm)

Comment: is it always just `hrs` and `m` or are there times it has `sec`?

Comment: are their times less than 1 hour?  if there are, does it display 0 hrs, or does it just show the minutes?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming formatting is all the same as mentioned this should work.

[image]

```
=SUM(LEFT(A1,SEARCH("hrs",A1)-1)+IFERROR(ROUND(SUM(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,SEARCH("hrs",A1)+3,LEN(A1)),"m",""))/60,10),0))
```

Had to move to substitute after a single format error.

Answer (score 2):

A little bit simpler formula:

```
=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,SEARCH("hrs",A1)+3,LEN(A1)),"m",""))/60+VALUE(LEFT(A1,SEARCH("hrs",A1)-1))
```

[image]